# Suggestions for a better headline graphic

Tags: discussion, design, theme

An answer to [DBA's updated site theme is ready for testing!](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3070) suggests that the headline graphic ought to be more reminiscent of an ERD diagram.

Before:

[image]

Now:

[image]

In a comment, Catija asked us to come up with a rough sketch for an improvement:

> I'm not sure this can be changed *now* but if one of y'all could mock up an example of what might make sense for this (maybe in a new question?), I can show it to the design team and they can work on something for this, maybe after the sites are all rolled out?
>
> A rough sketch or outline that the design team can work from is all I need! I'm not a database person (or an artist), so I'd hate to do either but knowing what looks "correct" from the start will help our designer get something that will look correct rather than looking like a circuit diagram or random lines and circles.

Please **contribute your suggestion as an answer** below.

Answer (score 23):

Based on [Crow's Foot notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Crow's_foot_notation):

[image]

Symbol reference:

[image: ERD Notation]
<sub>*[image source](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ER-diagram-symbols-and-meaning)*</sub>

Intended meanings as drawn (artistic licence employed):

- One (and only one) Database Administrators site
- Many questions
- Zero or many site achievements
- Zero or one featured meta questions (typically; *of course* right now we have two)

The far terminator is currently a circle. I guess this could be a diamond or something else from another ERD set, for variety. Or just remove it and the trailing line entirely.

Comment: "I guess this could be a diamond or something else from another ERD set" or just remove it and the trailing line entirely?

Comment: @JackDouglas Yes that would work too. Added.

Comment: Something like this could probably work. :) Thanks for the idea. It's worth keeping in mind that with the page width being responsive, where branches terminate may not make as much sense for all views or all users, but I think this is a good start. Feel free to keep spitballing! I'll keep an eye on this post.

Comment: @Catija Yes the primary meaning is in the symbols themselves. Where they link to (or not, as the responsiveness would have it) is pretty immaterial. I thought it would be nice to have some notes around my intent in this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Or perhaps something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

How about something like:

[image]

I'm sure the nice folks from Stackexchange can produce specs with exact dimensions and suchlike. If necessary I've got Adobe CS6, visio etc. and could knock up a model that's not based on someone's production system.

Getting the image to tesselate correctly down the left hand side of the page might need a bit of work.